# add_rewrite_rule() weird behaviour

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'am actually having weird problems whith add_rewrite_rule() :

```
function qvs( $vars ){
 $vars[]= 'myvar';
}
add_action( 'query_vars, 'qvs' );
function myrewrite(){
 add_rewrite_rule('something/([0-9]+), 'index.php?pagename=something&myvar=$matches[1]' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myrewrite' );
```

this simply doesn't write any rule in the .htaccess file

```
function myrewrite(){
 add_rewrite_rule('something/([0-9]+),'something/?myvar=$matches[1]' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'myrewrite' );
```

A rewriteRule is written :

`RewriteRule something/([0-9]+) /a-wordpress-plugins-work/something`/?myvar=$matches[1] [QSA,L]

But it doesn't work ... still ending to my 404 page

```
add_rewrite_rule('^something/([0-9]+), '/something/?myvar=$matches[1]' );
```

Prints a weird rule that looks like this :

```
RewriteRule ^^something/([\d]+) /a-wordpress-plugins-work//something/?myvar=$matches[1] [QSA,L]
```

Of course none of these are working ...

As soon as i use `'index.php?`...  the function fails writing anything in the .htacees file.

.... EUARRGG!!!! Pleease heeellllp !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rules are not stored in the htaccess file.. they are stored in 1 field in the options table..

There is this plugin: https://github.com/humanmade/hm-rewrite
it's a very light wrapper for url rewriting in wordpress, also is't better organized and more logic than the wordpress way. i suggest you give it a try.

It's does not do any magic stuff nor does it add any new tables or so.. just a wrapper :)

For the testing of the rule you could use: https://de-ch.wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/

Make sure you flush the rewrite rules after adding new ones.
You can flush them with this plugin or use the build in function called flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: Yes the rewrite_rule_inspector hepled seeing my rules where ok but 'top' parameter was missing. Thank's Bart !